# Making Div Overflow based on Image Size

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox, overflow

Is there a way to make a text div overflow without using fixed heights?

I have an image beside two text divs that I want to both overflow depending on their content while still keeping them vertically aligned with the image beside it. Using percentages, is the only way set the percentages of the parent all the way up to the html tag?

HTML:

```
<div class="content-container">
    <div class="list-container">
        <div class="amenities">
            <ol>
                <li>Aldi</li>
                <li>Swords Barber Shop</li>
                <li>The Warehouse Hair Salon</li>
                <li>Urban Vets</li>
                <li>Queen’s B’s Creche</li>
                <li>Royal Canal Park
                    Community Centre</li>
                <li>Pelletstown Educate
                    Together National School</li>
                <li>St Dominic's College</li>
                <li>Holy Family School for the Deaf </li>
                <li>Oliver Plunkett GAA club</li>
                <li>Royal Canal Kayak Cub</li>
                <li>Café Marmalade</li>
                <li>Breffni Inn</li>
                <li>Douglas and Kaldi </li>
                <li>The Lock Keeper</li>
                <li>The Halfway House</li>
                <li>Circle K Glasnevin</li>
                <li>Cafe 53</li>
                <li>Honest2Goodness</li>
                <li>Phoenix FC</li>
                <li>ParkHIIT Ashtown</li>
                <li>Violet Hill Park</li>
                <li>Glasnevin Cemetery</li>

            </ol>
        </div>
        <div class="transport">
            <ul>
                <li>r7547r</li>
                <li>457trjt</li>
                <li>457rtjrt</li>
                <li>uil0rtjr</li>
                <li>547jrtj</li>
                <li>rtj</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

   <div class="map-container">
       <img src="<?php echo $map['url']; ?>" alt="Map Image">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content-container{
  padding:4rem 0rem;
  display: flex;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color:$dark_blue;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;

  .heading-container{
    color:$dark_blue;
    flex-basis:0%;
    font-size:3.125rem;
    padding: 8rem 0rem;
    padding-right:4rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    h2{

      font-size:4.379rem;

      span{

      }
    }
  }

  .list-container{
    display: flex;
    width: 20%;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0rem 2rem;
    height: 100%;
    .amenities{
      background: $gold;
      overflow-y: scroll;
      height: 300px;

      ol {
        list-style: none;
        counter-reset: item;
      }
      li {
        counter-increment: item;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
      }
      li:before {
        margin-right: 10px;
        content: counter(item);
        background: black;
        border-radius: 100%;
        color: $gold;
        width: 1.2em;
        text-align: center;
        display: inline-block;
      }



    }
    .transport{


    }
  }
  .map-container{
    width: 80%;

  }

}
```

Design:
[image]

Comment: The browser needs to know the `height` of the tag when using `overflow`. What's the problem using percentage?